How can i index search through current running MacOS terminal sessions in Python?
I'm working a project that involves using Python, and i need a way to check if a certain keyword is in a terminal session from a Python script, how could i do that?
I wanted it to print "Very real" if "E1M3 - Toxin Refinery" had just been echo'd in any terminal session like from an application or anything.
I tried this script to try that:
import psutil
import re
import time
import sys

def get_terminal_sessions():
    terminal_sessions = []
    for process in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username', 'terminal']):
        try:
            if process.info['name'] == 'bash' or process.info['name'] == 'zsh':
                terminal_sessions.append(process)
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return terminal_sessions

def print_terminal_sessions(terminal_sessions):
    print("Terminal Sessions:")
    for session in terminal_sessions:
        print(f"PID: {session.pid} | User: {session.info['username']} | Terminal: {session.info['terminal']}")

def monitor_terminal_sessions():
    while True:
        terminal_sessions = get_terminal_sessions()
        for session in terminal_sessions:
            try:
                # Get terminal information
                terminal_path = session.info['terminal']
                with open(terminal_path, "r") as terminal:
                    lines = terminal.readlines()
                    for line in lines:
                        if re.search(r"E1M3 - Toxin Refinery", line):
                            print("VERY REAL")
                            sys.exit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                pass
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    monitor_terminal_sessions()


